# Want to install MYSQL 5.7 in Ubuntu 20.04 : GET ERROR Start request repeated to quickly

Tags: ubuntu, mysql

I need to install MySQL 5.7 on an Ubuntu 20.04: I did this [here](https://techexpert.tips/de/mysql-de/installieren-von-mysql-5-7-auf-ubuntu-20-04/). Before I did `apt purge mysql-client mysql-server` which removed the version 8.0.X from my system.

But at installing the `apt install mysql-community-server=5.7.35-1ubuntu18.04` I get the error:

```
    -- Automatic restarting of the unit mysql.service has been scheduled, as the 
       result for
    -- the configured Restart= setting for the unit.
    Okt 16 13:17:11 walter-CLS systemd[1]: Stopped MySQL Community Server.
    -- Subject: A stop job for unit mysql.service has finished
    -- Defined-By: systemd
    -- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
    -- 
    -- A stop job for unit mysql.service has finished.
    -- 
    -- The job identifier is 12725 and the job result is done.
    Okt 16 13:17:11 walter-CLS systemd[1]: mysql.service: Start request repeated too    quickly.
    Okt 16 13:17:11 walter-CLS systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
    -- Subject: Unit failed
    -- Defined-By: systemd
    -- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
    -- 
    -- The unit mysql.service has entered the 'failed' state with result 'exit-code'.
    Okt 16 13:17:11 walter-CLS systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Server.
    -- Subject: A start job for unit mysql.service has failed
    -- Defined-By: systemd
    -- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
    -- 
    -- A start job for unit mysql.service has finished with a failure.
```

Does anyone know what I could to to fix this?

Edit: My Reason for Using MySQL 5.7 on 20.04 Ubuntu is my old System is a Bionic 18.04 and there is Typo3 {7.6.2] and that works only with MySQL 5.7 and not MySQL 8.0.X which is on Ubuntu 20.04. If now was to bing the MySQL 5.7 to run on my 20.04 computer, I would like to know How I could upgrade my Typo 7.6.20 MySQL-DBs on my new PC for working with that `Typo3` suitable with MYSQL 8.0.X Here a list of compartibility: [Typo3_vs_MySQL](https://jweiland.net/typo3/versionen-und-updates.html)?

THanks

Answer (score 2):

The reason was, that I had old MYSQL DBs (for 8.0) in `/var/lib/mysql`. After I had deleted them I could do it.